# dynamic DOM diff modification from ajax and liquid

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, diff, liquid

I've written an implementation of [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) that can be used dynamically within HTML, and is parsed by JavaScript. In turn, I'm using AJAX to provide a data source. This looks something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Which would be handled similarly to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "response.json",
  success: function(data) {
    var template = document.getElementById('container'),
        parse1 = Liquid.parse(template.innerHTML);

    template.innerHTML = parse.render(data);
  }
});
```

Now, assuming the `$.ajax` is being called every so often, the contents of `#container` is updated with anything that might have changed. The issue with doing this, is that **EVERYTHING** is reloaded, opposed to just what's changed; you loose text selection, things like "active" tabs, etc..

To solve this, I've been using [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch) to compare two rendered strings before replacing, which in turn gives me the positions of each change, so I can loop through the HTML and modify them.

After getting all this working, I've come to realize something very fatal to my plan:

```
template.innerHTML[###] = 'new content';
```

does not work in the slightest. Apparently I can't modify the innerHTML of an element based on its string index.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a simpler way of doing this?

With whatever you recommend, keep in mind that I don't have control over the DOM elements. Whatever Liquid is parsing needs to be agnostic to its replace logic (ie, I can't use ID's, classes, etc.).

The only solutions I can think of are:

- Somehow get what I'm trying to do above working... that'd be lovely.
- Creating a DOM diff-match-patch and handle things that way (or use one that exists for the browser?)